# Workflow rule using formula using multiple fields in criteria to update fields

Tags: workflow, validation-rule

I'm using a formulas to verify if 2 fields have changed from specific values to specific values. When I applied it to 1 field it works. I'm having trouble verifying 2 fields in the formula. Can I please get help tweaking this formula below. I want that if both `Status__c` and `Approval_Progres__c` are changed from *New* to *Active*/*Approved*:

```
AND( 
  ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status__c),'New'), 
  ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Active") && ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Approval_Progress__c),'New'), 
  ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Approved"))
```

Comment: It's not clear whether both fields could change their values to Active and/or Approved. And if so, why would you have 2 different fields having the same values and changing them at the same time (at least this is how it's looking from your question). Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a peaceful person. I try not to be hateful in any way.

But of the few things that I truly do hate I have to include the `AND()` and `OR()` functions in Salesforce formulas.

I believe they were once necessary, and people who grew up with Excel formulas really like them. So truly, different strokes...and all...

But I hate them.

I hate them because they are really hard to read, IMO...all the commas...you don't know when they are going end...etc.

Your current formula would be true if:

1. The prior value of `Status__c` is *New*
2. The current `Status__c` value is *Active* and the prior value of `Approval_Progress__c` is *New*
3. The current value of `Status__c` is *Active*

Status cannot be both Active and Approved at the same time!

Perhaps this is your problem.

```
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status__c),'New') &&
ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Active") &&
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Approval_Progress__c),'New') &&
ISPICKVAL(Approval_Progress__c, "Approved")
```

(Note the different field name of the last `ISPICKVAL`).

Comment: I'm personally prefer && as well, but many SF admins coming from the business side (and not just them) might prefer to use AND and OR formulas to their similarity with Excel equivalents. There is a great chrome extension [https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforcecom-enhanced-fo/cnlnnpnjccjcmecojdhgpknalcahkhio] that helps editing SF formulas.

Comment: Thank you peter your syntax has solved my problem. Although I am and old Excel user myself and I've done complex AND/OR formulas before. I too was struggling with the "AND" .So && was the right way to go. I'd be very interested to know what I did wrong though with the "AND" as I've tried all suggestion provided in this thread

Comment: This syntax I had with AND was a Typo error. So now they both work. <CODE> AND( 
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status__c),"New"), ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Active"), 
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Approval_Progress__c), "New"), 
ISPICKVAL(Approval_Progress__c, "Approved")) </CODE>

Comment: I'm just being silly...tongue in cheek. `AND` and `OR` work just fine. But part of writing code (or formulas in this case) is how readable it is for yourself when you write it, when you go back to it later, and when someone else is reading it. I find the `AND` and `OR` quite unreadable, especially in more complex scenarios. So yeah...works fine...

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to validate  it only if both of the fields have changed from value A to value B then this should be it:

```
   AND( 
    ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status__c),'New'), 
    ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Active") , 
    ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Approval_Progress__c),'New'), 
    ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Approved")
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bit strange mixing ampersands with the "AND" function. Can you try replacing the `&&` with a comma? Like so:

```
    AND( 
    ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status__c),'New'), 
    ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Active"),
    ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Approval_Progress__c),'New'), 
    ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Approved"))
```